# How to fix PyException error in Sikulix 1.1.1?

Tags: sikuli, jython-2.5, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am facing the below error in my sikuli script

```
+++ running this Java
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
+++ trying to run SikuliX
+++ using: -Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine -jar
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\UI_testing\Setup\sikulix.jar
[info] HotkeyManager: add Capture Hotkey: CTRL+SHIFT 2 (50, 3)
[info] HotkeyManager: add Abort Hotkey: ALT+SHIFT C (67, 9)
[error] IDE: Remembered window not valid. Going to primary screen

Exception: **org.python.core.PyException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler
in thread "Thread-13"**
```

Checked and found the code is getting stuck at a line where I used image as a dictionary element

```
for i in menubar:
    exists(menubar[i]).highlight(3)
```

`menubar` is a python dictionary which contains images which are stored with their name as key.

PS : code

```
from sikuli import *
menubar={"file":"menubar_file.png","edit":"menubar_edit.png","view":"menubar_view.png","administration":"menubar_administration.png","tools":"menubar_tools.png","help":"menubar_help.png"}

for i in menubar:
    assert exists(menubar[i]).highlight(2)
```

Comment: paste full code please

Comment: So which code are you actually using, with or without the assertion?

Comment: The one in **PS** , with assertion

Answer (score 0):

The `assert` statement is testing a boolean expression that evaluates to `True` or `False`. The Sikuli `exists()` function however returns a `Match` object if a pattern found or `None` in the pattern was not found. You need to rewrite your code accordingly.

Also, I wouldn't use the `highlight()` like this as it is not clear what it is highlighting.